# Chances of drawing a card of specific color

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Deck contains cards of various colors. I want to draw a red card from a deck.

Which deck complication approach gives me more chances:

a) 60 cards, 4 colors (15 x each color) OR b) 50 cards, 5 colors (10 x each color).

Case 1: Chances of drawing a card at a first draw.

Is it simply a matter of 15/60 (0.25) in case a) and 10/50 (0.2) case b) or there is more to this case, e.g. taking into consideration deck size or 4 vs 5 colors?

Case 2: How many draws do I need on average to draw a red card?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For case $1$, it is just the number of red cards divided by the number of cards, as you did. For case $2$, you must consider that the chance to get no red card, decreases whenever a card not being red was drawn. Now, calculate the chance to fail to draw a red card $2,3,4\cdots$ times.

Comment: Do we replace the drawn card or not ? I assumed we don't.

Comment: If it is uniform, then it's simply 1/4 and 1/5 resp. Average in the first case is 4, second case 5.